# HBase responses with the invalid data

Tags: hbase, rpc, database-scan

Here's the debug log from RegionServer.

```
2014-09-23,14:57:59,107 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner: Creating scanner over .META. starting at key 'miliao_user_seq,,'
2014-09-23,14:57:59,107 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner: Advancing internal scanner to startKey at 'miliao_user_seq,,'
2014-09-23,14:57:59,107 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP sending #204
2014-09-23,14:57:59,108 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP got value #204
2014-09-23,14:57:59,108 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #204 state is 0
2014-09-23,14:57:59,108 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #204, response is:
OW[class=long,value=-16338305647227588]
2014-09-23,14:57:59,108 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureRpcEngine: Call: openScanner 1
2014-09-23,14:57:59,108 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP sending #205
2014-09-23,14:57:59,109 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP got value #205
2014-09-23,14:57:59,109 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #205 state is 0
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #205, response is:
OW[class=class [Lorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;,value=[Lorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;@2081ca25]
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureRpcEngine: Call: next 2
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.HBaseClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP sending #206
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: IPC Client (847446306) connection to lg-hadoop-srv-st04.bj/10.2.201.77:13600 from hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP got value #206
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #206 state is 0
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #206, response is:
OW[class=void,value=null]
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureRpcEngine: Call: close 0
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager: Try to delete HConnection, connectionKey=HConnectionKey{properties={hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=11000, hbase.client.pause=200, zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase/lgsrv-miliao, hbase.client.retries.number=4, hbase.zookeeper.quorum=10.101.10.66,10.101.10.67,10.2.201.73,10.2.201.74,10.2.201.75}, username='hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP'}, stopProxy=false, staleConnection=false
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker: Stopping catalog tracker org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.CatalogTracker@40128340
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager: Try to delete HConnection, connectionKey=HConnectionKey{properties={hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=11000, hbase.client.pause=200, zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase/lgsrv-miliao, hbase.client.retries.number=4, hbase.zookeeper.quorum=10.101.10.66,10.101.10.67,10.2.201.73,10.2.201.74,10.2.201.75}, username='hbase_srv/hadoop@XIAOMI.HADOOP'}, stopProxy=false, staleConnection=false
2014-09-23,14:57:59,111 DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Closing session: 0x4877f5617edf6d
```

You can see the data it got. It's quite abnormal and I have no idea why it's that. By the way, I can get the correct result in HBase shell when scanning tables.

```
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #205, response is:
OW[class=class [Lorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;,value=[Lorg.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;@2081ca25]
```

```
2014-09-23,14:57:59,110 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.SecureClient: call #206, response is:
OW[class=void,value=null]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems not a problem. And I can scan META table and get the correct result.